# Cannot resolve symbol "txt_level" Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dis);

        textview_level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_level);
    }
```

The problem is with this line: `textview_level = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_level);`
It doesn't seem to pick up my id from the XML file, however it picks up the id's from the `activity_main`, even though i have `setContentView` to `activity_dis`.
I have ran a clean build on the program, as well as copying the code to a new project, but the problem still persists.

Here is the code for `activity_main`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:id="@+id/btnstart"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Stop Scanning"
        android:id="@+id/btnstop"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/listviewp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:maxLines="30" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for `activity_dis`:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="3"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".Dis" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center" />



    <TextView
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd" />

    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/txt_level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textSize="150sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"

        android:layout_row="1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text=""
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"

        android:layout_row="1"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Remain"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_row="2"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="L"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_row="2"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="R"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        android:layout_row="2"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:text="Warning"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="18sp" />
</GridLayout>
```

this is the TextView which its id will not show:

```
    <TextView
        android:id = "@+id/txt_level"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:textSize="150sp" />
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your cache, go to File > Invalidate cache + restart

Answer (score 0):

First Option >> go to build >> Select Clean Project >> After Rebuild Project.
OR
Second Option >> Invalid Catches / Restart Option.